# How to join CD tracks when importing CD on iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I have audiobooks with multiple tracks on each CD. I would like to consolidate all the tracks on one CD into a single track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing your CD in iTunes:

1. Select all the tracks you want to consolidate
2. Under the "**Options**" menu, click on "**Join CD tracks**"
3. Click on "**Import**" and iTunes will import your CD, merging the tracks you joined into one single track

[Source](https://www.kirkville.com/itunes-12-join-tracks-when-importing-cds/)